# hp-ux mount a disk to recover data

Tags: mount, hp-ux

Had a problem booting from a disk, installed a newly imaged disk, booted fine.  I'd like to try to mount the problem disk and using sam I can see the disk fine.  However I cannot figure out how to mount the disk and retain the current data.  Read Man pages and searched HP's forums found some mount instructions but nothing that directly applied to mounting an old lvm drive.  If anyone has any ideas i'd sure appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the commands I was looking for were vgimport and vgchange.  Because I wanted to mount a drive that already had volume group info on it and didn't want that info to be over written.

So the steps ended up being.

1. mkdir /somedir
2. mknode /somedir/node
3. vgimport /somedir /dev/dsk/disk
4. vgchange -a y /somedir
5. then use SAM to mount the logical volume.

   In my case SAM reported a corrupt disk error, so I also ran:
6. fsck -F vxfs -o full -y /somedir/rlvol#

Then went back to SAM and it mounted fine.  Recovered data, felt lucky, had a good day!

Comment: Since there were errors on the disk the data you recovered may be corrupt.  If you have any way to check the integrity of the restored files I would recommend doing so.

Comment: I think the sections of the disk that were corrupt were boot sections.  The data recovered are text files used to configure machines for testing so they must be compiled for each setup and corruption would show up during compile and should be pretty easily found and corrected.  Thanks though.  Also this disk will not be used in production setting really just needed to get data off. For some reason it missed a scheduled backup.

Answer (score 1):

Any case when there might be a HDD problem the best way is to create an image from the broken harddrive with dd and mount that.